# React: useEffect performance issue on Android app webview?

Tags: android, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am building a web page with React using the `useEffect` hook api

but when I open the page in the webview of my client's android app, it always take more than 5000ms between first render call and the useEffect call.

here is my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const api = {
  ins: axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://new.h5no1.com/apg-great-china-3/api'
  })
};

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const t = useRef(Date.now());
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(Date.now() - t.current); // 5000+, useLayoutEffect log 30~50 only
    api.ins
      .post('/user/is_on_list', {
        openid: 'xxx',
        openToken: 'xxx'
      })
      .then(res => {
        setData(JSON.stringify(res.data))
      });
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{data ? data : 'loading'}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

and when I change to use the `useLayoutEffect`, it works fine, the problem is, I don't why using `useEffect` can cause an issue here while just using it to fetch data from web api ?

the UA string I get from the webview of the app

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; MI 8 Lite Build/PKQ1.181007.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Mobile Safari/537.36 PARS/50601
```

I have tested on other android devices with the app, they all behaved the same.

and using `componentDidMount` works fine, too.

Comment: have you tried if the same happens in mobile browser? may it be an issue in render/JS engine of webview?

Comment: it only happens on that app, I opened the page in default browser and chrome, everything looks fine, and the same issue happens on other android devices

Answer (score 0):

useLayoutEffect is synonym for componentDidMount in term of execution. Easiest case looks like this: render => useLayoutEffect(componentDidMount ) => animationFrame => useEffect. It basically means that if you have some blocking execution in rendering or in layout effect then useEffect will be delayed. This is react behaviour not android specific tho.

Comment: but it only happens on that android app I mentioned, I tried some other apps on the same device, it works fine. this is the app download link, https://android.myapp.com/myapp/detail.htm?apkName=com.pingan.lifeinsurance you can tap the top left icon and scan a url qrcode to open any webpage, I just don't understand why `=> animationFrame =>` takes so long on that app

Comment: ...but OP sees opposite: `useEffect` blocks rendering somehow while `useLayoutEffect` does not

Comment: dunno what you mean by OP. well it is still javascript so yeah.. the order of execution looks like i have mentioned.. but yeah if you menage to not block with layoutEffect useEffect is executed and useEffect is just another javascript task running on the event loop so it can for sure be blocking.